# How to use new NavigationStart @angular-router 3.0.0-alpha.*

Tags: typescript, angular

I see these new events in the new Angular 2 Router.

Theres NavigationStart, NavigationEnd, NavigationFailed (or something like that)

Does anyone know how to use these yet? I've messed around with a few things but haven't been able to get them to do anything.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The `Router` provides an `events` observable that can be subscribed to

```
constructor(router:Router) {
  router.events.subscribe(event => {
    if(event instanceof NavigationStart) {
    }
    // NavigationEnd
    // NavigationCancel
    // NavigationError
    // RoutesRecognized
  }
});
```

See also

- https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/Router-interface.html
- https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/NavigationStart-class.html
- https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/NavigationEnd-class.html
- https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/NavigationCancel-class.html
- https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/NavigationError-class.html
- https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/RoutesRecognized-class.html

**NOTE**

don't forget to import `NavigationStart` from `router` module

```
import { Router, NavigationStart } from '@angular/router';
```

because if you don't import it `instanceof` will not work and an error `NavigationStart is not defined` will rise.

Comment: I see this error with RC4, `Unhandled Promise rejection: (SystemJS) Error: Cannot resolve all parameters for 'Router'(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?). Make sure that all the parameters are decorated with Inject or have valid type annotations and that 'Router' is decorated with Injectable`. I handled it with ROUER_PROVIDERS with RC2, but don't know how with RC4 because couldn't find it with RC4. any hint or plunker you have?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be related to this question or my answer. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/38555016/217408

Comment: When using this, you may also need to import "Event" from @angular/router.  Otherwise, TypeScript will use regular window.Event, which NavigationStart will not resolve to.

Comment: Are you putting this in the AppModule constructor?

Comment: No, in the constructor of a component or service. It might even work in the constructor of `AppModule` (never tried), but I don't see how it would be useful there ;-)

Comment: it is hard to always learn the docs by heart if an update occurs :D

Comment: @oooyaya - I imported `Event` from `@angular/router`,but I get compile error. I had to remove it from `@angular/router` and just do `router.events.subscribe(event => { ... })` for it to work (i.e., change `event:Event` to `event`).

Comment: I think it should still work https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/Event-type-alias.html

Comment: if I want a segment of url and I dont want do split, exist any class that give me a segment url

Answer (score 8):

Just like this

```
 constructor(
  private router:Router
 ){}
 this.router.events
  .filter(event=> event instanceof NavigationStart)
  .subscribe((event:NavigationStart)=>{
     // TODO
  });
```

Comment: `Property 'filter' does not exist on type 'Observable<Event>'.`

Comment: You need to import the filter operator, otherwise you will get this error. `import 'rxjs/add/operator/filter'`

Comment: filter no longer exist on Observable as of rxjs 7.

Answer (score 0):

In order for this to work, you need to add `.pipe()`

```
this.router.events
  .pipe(filter((event) => event instanceof NavigationStart))
  .subscribe((event: NavigationStart) => {
   // YOUR code
  });
```