# Angular 2 rc3 Router subscribe

Tags: angular, router

In angular2 rc1 I subscribe for a change of route:

```
this.router.changes.subscribe(
() => {
    console.log(this.location.path());
});
```

How I can subscribe to change route in angular2 rc3?
router.changes already doesn't exists.

Comment: I think this is a dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37977428/how-to-use-new-navigationstart-angular-router-3-0-0-alpha

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
constructor(router:Router) {
  router.events.subscribe(event:Event => {
    if(event instanceof NavigationStart) {
    }
    // NavigationEnd
    // NavigationCancel
    // NavigationError
    // RoutesRecognized
  }
}
```

or

```
constructor(router:Router) {
  router.events.forEach(event:Event => {
```

Comment: Is if(event is NavigationStart) sudo code? no such thing as 'is' in Javascript is there? I can't figure out a way to check for a specific event like you're showing in the example.

Comment: Use if(event instanceof NavigationStart)  instead of is

Comment: Thanks @KrishnanunniJeevan. Sorry, mixed some Dart into the code - fixed.

Answer (score 3):

```
constructor(private router: Router) {
  this.router.events.subscribe(event => {
    if (event.constructor.name === 'NavigationStart') {
      console.log(event.url);
    }
  });
}
```