# Angular router 3 wildcard matching

Tags: angularjs, angular

What is wrong with following route configuration? I am always navigated to `**` even if there is a route for `app/jungle`.

```
import {bootstrap} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';


import { RouterConfig, provideRouter } from '@angular/router@3.0.0-beta.2'

import {App} from './app';
import { HomeComponent } from './home.component';
import { JungleComponent } from './jungle.component';
import { NotFoundComponent } from './not-found.component';



const APP_ROUTES: RouterConfig = [
  {
    path: '', pathMatch: '', redirectTo: 'app/home'
  },
  {
    path: 'app/', pathMatch: '', redirectTo: 'app/home'
  },
  {
    path: 'app/home', component: HomeComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'app/jungle', component: JungleComponent
  },
  {
    path: '**', component: NotFoundComponent
  }
]

bootstrap(App, [provideRouter(APP_ROUTES)])
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/sM0ckvL7qwSOOYZRdCbK?p=preview) is a plunker.
**I am using @angular/router@3.0.0-beta.2**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`''` is an invalid value for `pathMatch`.

`pathMatch` supports `full` and `prefix`. `prefix` is the default.

Set it to `'full'` for the first two routes:

```
{
  path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'app/home'
},

{
  path: 'app/', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'app/home'
},

{
path: 'app/home', component: HomeComponent
},

{
  path: 'app/jungle', component: JungleComponent
},

{
  path: '**', component: NotFoundComponent}
]
```

[**Plunker example**](http://plnkr.co/edit/tweeAhiBtYMMnf3sOi08?p=preview)

**Update** (according to the comment below)

I don't know exactly why the trailing `/` makes it work but I would use componentless parent routes instead like

```
const APP_ROUTES: RouterConfig = [
{ path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'app/home' },
{ path: 'app', children: [
  { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'home' },
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'jungle', component: JungleComponent },
]},
{ path: '**', component: NotFoundComponent }]
```

[**Plunker example**](http://plnkr.co/edit/LahJRkyN53jnN0SzQQa4?p=preview)

Comment: Wow, that actually solved the problem but if I changed `{
  path: 'app/', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'app/home'
}` to `{
  path: 'app', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'app/home'
}` (**notice the back slash at the end of path property**) gives the same problem as before. Any clue on that

Comment: I didn't see the slash. I'll check again.

Comment: Very elegant solution, worked like a charm. I changed my route configuration to match your later configuration structure and.. and... and..... yes! the issue is resolved. Many many thanks!