# Can I add a process to every component's ngOnInit and OnDestroy?

Tags: angular

I have an observable that I need to bind and remove on every component.

Is it possible to write the subscribe/unsubscribe logic somewhere and have it implicitly included in every component?

Like a middleware on the creation/destruction of a component

Here is an example of what I'd like to see:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9iBo.png

edit: yurzui gave me the idea to use `super.ngOnInit()`
Not as clean as I'd like, but hey - it works.

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';

export class ExtendHooks {
  ngOnDestroy() {
    console.log("Want this to fire first")
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('Want to fire first')
  }
}


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent extends ExtendHooks implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  constructor(){
    super()
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    super.ngOnDestroy()
    console.log("Want this to fire second")
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    super.ngOnInit()
    console.log("Want to fire second")    
  }
}
```

Comment: You can make a base class with this code and make every concrete component a subclass of that base class. This works only for your own components, not for 3rd-party.

Comment: use ngOnInit and ngOnDestroy on the components were you want to subscribe and unsubscribe. check life cycle hooks https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks

Comment: Thanks for your response. Günter, here is an update of what I would like to see, however the hooks do not execute from the base class. https://i.imgur.com/K8XtaFv.png

Comment: Try `super.ngOnDestroy()`

Comment: same issue
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37977428/how-to-use-new-navigationstart-angular-router-3-0-0-alpha

Answer (score 0):

Try router lifecycle hooks navigationstart and navigationend